# SocialEngine Profile Page

Tags: php, socialengine

I have just started using SocialEngine PHP. I am wondering if anyone knows where to find the php file for Sign Up > Create Account in application/modules/User/Form/Signup/Account . I cannot seem to find the file that corresponds to for Sign-Up > Profile Information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SE4 is complex piece of code (MVC with a lot of hooks, plugins, widgets), if you look into User_SignupController::indexAction(), you find something like:

```
$formSequenceHelper = $this->_helper->formSequence;
foreach( Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('signup', 'user')->fetchAll() as $row ) {
  if( $row->enable == 1 ) {
    $class = $row->class;
    $formSequenceHelper->setPlugin(new $class, $row->order);
  }
}
```

Well, look into engine4_user_signup table now:

```
SELECT * FROM `engine4_user_signup` ORDER BY `order`;
```

You will get list of models, which be included as plugins into signup process (look for source in the application/modules/User/Plugin/Signup). User_Plugin_Signup_Fields is your prize. Or first piece of it, I don't know what you look for exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Controller is: `User/controllers/SignupController/Index`

And many functions which are being called after signup hook are under `User_Plugin_Signup_Account`.